# how to call a method in Stateless EJB during deployment?

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

How can i tell a application server to call a method in my stateless ejb so that I can print some message during deployment. If I annotate the method with @PostConstruct then it is not working. I also added static block still not working. I dont want to use MBean. Also my ear does not have any web project. So I can not use any servlet and its init method to print such messages.

Server we are using is Jboss.

thanks

Comment: Jboss already prints deployting.. and deployed messages for ejb.

Comment: What if I want to use application specific messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in EJB 3.0.

[Eager / auto loading of EJB / load EJB on startup (on JBoss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707733/eager-auto-loading-of-ejb-load-ejb-on-startup-on-jboss)

Comment: Excellent! this saves a lot of time for me. Looks like only way for us now is to use Servlet

Comment: @user509755 you could also create a singleton startup bean that does the initialisation for you.

Comment: @Laures The question is specifically tagged ejb-3.0, but the link does show an example of @Startup @Singleton.