# JAX-RS: How to run a method on start (without servlets)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS (Jersey) server with which I register and bind my stuff.

I want to print a banner when the server starts up.  I want to do this using the JAX-RS framework ***not*** the web server's platform (i.e., no Jetty, Netty, Thorntail, etc hooks).

I saw the following which mentions the tried and true Servlet way of doing things: 
[Jax rs: How can I run a method automatically everytime my server restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650520/jax-rs-how-can-i-run-a-method-automatically-everytime-my-server-restarts) , but that does not work because I am not running a servlet container in my server so that lifecycle call is never made.

I figured there must be a JCA-ish type object that I can register with `Application`/`ResourceConfig` that has such a lifecycle call, but I am unable to even find any kind of list of the things you can actually register.

Not to complain (but I will), but I cannot decide if this is so difficult because when they moved the project to eclipse, they broke every hyperlink to the old official documentation or that it is simply so implicit, like Spring, that it only works by github'ing other people's code and realizing, 'oh, I did not know you could do that'.

Comment: Jersey has [event listeners](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16007)

Comment: Thanks.  Did not expect it to be under 'monitoring' chapter.  If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey has [Event Listeners](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16007). You'll want to use the [`ApplicationEventListener`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.27/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener.html) and the [`ApplicationEvent.Type`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.27/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEvent.Type.html) you'll probably want to listen for to print the banner is the `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED`

```
public class MyApplicationEventListener
            implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case INITIALIZATION_FINISHED:
                printBanner();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```